# Error faultCode argument for createFault was passed NULL

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, wsdl, cxf, soapui

Hello I generated a customer by SoapUI using CXF, gave no error message or warning , the client implementation, as follows down, I just set the object I want to search and step into the research method, the binding of the wsdl the search method does not have the fault operation.

**There is no operation of the search method in the binding .**

```
<wsdl:fault name="fault">
    <soap:fault use="literal" name="fault"/>
  </wsdl:fault>
```

**Implementation**

```
SearchRestriction search = new SearchRestriction();
        search.setFieldName("Serviço Público:serviceID");
        search.setOperator("EQUALS");
        search.setValue("deleteAddress");

        com.sensedia.repository.wstoolkit.SearchRequest _search_in = new SearchRequest();
        _search_in.getRestrictions().add(search);

        java.util.List<com.sensedia.repository.wstoolkit.SearchResult> _search__return = null;
        try {
            _search__return = port.search(_search_in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `faultCode argument for createFault was passed NULL` is generated by CXF client in case of receiving of SOAP response with a Fault element without a valid `faultCode` sub-element. Capture SOAP server response and verify its validity. Below is a sample of a valid SOAP server response with a Fault element. Please note that elements `faultcode` and `faultstring` are provided without namespace.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">Binding error</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```